# issues with using mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to convert my mysql_connect codes to mysqli_connect and the following is my code block...I can login to the DB but there must be some issues with mysqli_fetch_array() function...can anyone please guide me where i miss it...

```
$con= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql="SELECT username,password FROM login WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pass'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["username"],$row["password"]);
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

But it gives me ()() this as result...

Comment: Use parameterized queries. This is open to SQL injections....and passwords should be hashed.

Comment: You should check if it has any error>>> $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); and then print_r($row) and see what you get

Comment: Your SELECT query is completely pointless you're selecting the Username / password where username and password equal the already defined supplied values.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator..thanks this error handling actually helps me alot to to figure out the issue...

Comment: you should exit a script if you stumble on connect to db error - doesn't make much sense to continue...

Answer (score -1):

I think you have problem with your query

```
$sql="SELECT username,password FROM login 
      WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pass'";
```

Instead of this use

```
$sql="SELECT username,password FROM login 
      WHERE username='".$uname.'" AND password='".$pass."'";
```

Comment: This may be correct but OPs use of passwords is completely wrong. Passwords should not be checked in the database, but hashes generated and only the hashes should be checked.